# Why is .htaccess always returning the target page as a variable here?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?query=$1
```

however no matter what i type into the url, `$1` is always equal to `page.php`

What I Expect to happen:

```
myurl.com/test   >> myurl.com/page.php?query=test
```

What is happening:

```
myurl.com/test >> myurl.com/page.php?query=page.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have 2 redirects taking place.  `page.php` itself is being redirected to `page.php?query=page.php`.  You need to exclude it from the redirect.  Better yet, exclude all real existing files and directories.  Also, add `[QSA'] to append any additional querystring params, as well as`[L]` to stop processing any further rewrites that may come later in the file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

# if the request is NOT for a real file or directory
# (page.php is a real existing file)
# do the rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```